# Utilisation du mot « hélas »

Tags: sens, interjections

Je voudrais savoir quand on peut utiliser le mot « hélas ».

1. Est-ce qu'il est fréquement utilisé ?
2. Qu'est-ce qu'il exprime exactement ? Et dans quel contexte on peut l'utiliser ?

Comment: *Hélas* est peu utilisé. Un synonyme très utilisé est *malheureusement*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Le cntrl](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/h%C3%A9las)*  vous fournit les nuances et usages de *hélas*.

C'est un mot peu fréquemment utilisé au XXIe siècle.

On le trouve dans les contes, la littérature ou pour ponctuer les dialogues cinématographiques d'humour ou de gravité.

Je l'entends assez rarement dans les conversations :

- soit il abonde dans le regret du locuteur,
- soit il marque une ironie, une urbanité quelque peu suspecte.

L'utiliser au sens premier de *regret* est d'un style soutenu plus facile à l'écrit, s'en servir avec ironie ou malice demande un bonne connaissance des usages et des codes sociaux des interlocuteurs présents.

Comment: par urbanité vous entendez quoi ?

Comment: "Politesse ou entre beaucoup d'affabilité naturelle et d'usage du monde" selon Le Robert. Pratiquement quelqu'un de jovial, avenant, dont le langage s'adapte à son auditoire, son exquise politesse valorise ceux à qui il parle ; on se sent à l'aise avec quelqu'un d'urbain et la conversation est facilité  par sa capacité d'écoute et ses réponses appropriées.

Answer (score 4):

**Hélas**, selon le TLFi, est une interjection décrite comme suit : "*réaction à une situation ou à un propos que le locuteur présente (par l'énonciation même de hélas) comme pénibles ou douloureux*". Son emploi est vieilli et se trouve davantage dans la littérature (et notamment au théâtre) que dans une utilisation de la vie courante. Il peut cependant être employé de manière ironique, pour souligner par exemple une dramatisation.

"Il ne peut pas venir, hélas..." sera compris comme signifiant que le locuteur est heureux que la personne ne puisse venir.

Answer (score 2):

"Hélas" exprime la même chose que "malheureusement" :

Par exemple :

"Hélas, il est mort avant" => "Malheureusement, il est mort avant"